# How to pass data to a monkeypatch in pytest

Tags: python-3.x, properties, pytest, fixtures, monkeypatching

I have a simple test, where I would like to test the correct creation of the user data.
The `Data` creation is depending on the user's week (you can consider it as a week joined). This means that users with `week=2` should have all `Data` objects which are also have `week=2`. Since I have users with a different week, I want my test to cover several weeks. My problem here is that `User.week` is a property that uses calculations to get a real week number and I don't know how to pass the `week` parameter to my monkeypatch fixture to make static value be "dynamic".

Now I have an ugly solution that works for me - I have created two the same mocks with different return values.

test_tasks.py

```
from users.tasks import create_default_data_for_user

class TestUserTasks:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "week",
        ["mock_user_week_1", "mock_user_week_2"]
    )
    def test_create_default_data_for_user(self, user, rf, data, week):
        """
        Check creation of user data using create_default_data_for_user task.

        :param user: a user object fixture
        :param rf: instance of Django test RequestFactory
        :param data: fixture that creates default data object
        :param week: mock object of user's week property
        :return:
        """

        # Make sure the user has no user data
        assert len(user.data_set.all()) == 0

        create_default_data_for_user()

        # Now the user should be given data according to his week
        expected_user_data_count = Data.objects.filter(week=user.week).count()

        assert len(user.data_set.all()) == expected_user_data_count

        # Make sure that for the current user the second run will not cause user data duplication
        create_default_data_for_user()
        assert len(user.data_set.all()) == expected_user_data_count
```

fixtures.py

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def mock_user_week_1(monkeypatch):
    """
    Mock the User object's property week.

    The mock object will prevent calculation of the real User's week
    and just return a given number.
    """

    @property
    def user_week(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        A mock object that overrides the method and returns a static value.

        :param args: args of the original object
        :param kwargs: kwargs of the original object
        :return: static value indicating week number 1
        """
        return 1

    monkeypatch.setattr(
        User,
        "week",
        user_week
    )


@pytest.fixture
def mock_user_week_2(monkeypatch):
    """
    Mock the User object's property week.

    The mock object will prevent calculation of the real User's week
    and just return a given number.
    """

    # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    @property
    def user_week(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        A mock object that overrides the method and returns a static value.

        :param args: args of the original object
        :param kwargs: kwargs of the original object
        :return: static value indicating week number 2
        """
        return 2

    monkeypatch.setattr(
        User,
        "week",
        user_week
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got it.
The solution turned out to be simple:

fixtures.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_user_week(monkeypatch, week_number):
    """
    Mock the User object's method week.

    The mock object will prevent calculation of the real User's week
    and just return a given number.
    """

    @property
    def user_week(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        A mock object that overrides the method and return static value.

        :param args: args of the original object
        :param kwargs: kwargs of the original object
        :return: static value indicating week number
        """

        return week_number

    monkeypatch.setattr(
        User,
        "week_in_program",
        user_week
    )
```

test_tasks.py

```
from users.tasks import create_default_data_for_user

class TestUserTasks:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "week_number",
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    )
    def test_create_default_data_for_user(self, user, rf, data, week_number, mock_user_week):
        """
        Check creation of user data using create_default_data_for_user task.

        :param user: a user object fixture
        :param rf: instance of Django test RequestFactory
        :param data: fixture that creates default data object
        :param int week_number: user's week to be used
        :param mock_user_week: mock object of user's week property
        :return:
        """

        # Make sure the user has no user data
        assert len(user.data_set.all()) == 0

        create_default_data_for_user()

        # Now the user should be given data according to his week
        expected_user_data_count = Data.objects.filter(week=user.week).count()

        assert len(user.data_set.all()) == expected_user_data_count

        # Make sure that for the current user the second run will not cause user data duplication
        create_default_data_for_user()
        assert len(user.data_set.all()) == expected_user_data_count
```

The "magic" here is that I use the parameter `week_number` in the parametrize, in the test method arguments, and in the mock fixture. Thus pytest passes this argument both to the test method and the mock fixture. In this particular case, each `parametrize` run will cause a new return value from the mock fixture. And in the test, I'm creating `Data` objects for different weeks from the given list.
I couldn't even think that pytest itself passes arguments to fixtures without additional "settings".

It would be great to have things like this in the documentation.